# JQuery > operation not work

Tags: jquery

i have an operation into if condation that its not working true in this line    if( score > tot){
i have two number in these variable it doesnt check true and total is bigger than score but return false not work .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".saveMarkList").click(function(event){
            var score = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
            var total = $(this).closest('tr').find('label').text();
            var tot = $.trim(total);                        
                if( score > tot){ 
                return false;                   
                }else if(score == '' ){ 
                return false;                   
                }else if( tot == '' ){ 
                return false;                   
                }                   
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var savebtnTD =  $(this).closest('tr').find('span');
            var subjectId = $(".suid").prop('id');
            var senfId = $(".senfid").prop('id');
            var studentId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').next('td').prop('id');
            var assesmentId = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();



            var url = "<?php echo base_url().'examination/saveMarkList';?>";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {'subjectId': subjectId, 'senf_id':senfId, 'studentId': studentId, 'assId': assesmentId, 'score': score},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result){
                    if(result){
                        //row.css('border', '2px solid green');
                        savebtnTD.css('border', '2px solid green; color: green;').html('<span>دخیره شد</span>');
                    }else{
                        alert(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Some technical problem");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show an example of score and total?

Comment: when i put variables in alert its show me true my number but in checking its not work

Comment: *total is bigger than score* then the condition is right, score is not bigger than total. Did you mean  `if(tot > score){`

Comment: create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net with values set and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the values as numbers, not strings.

You can convert values to ints faster than `parseInt` using `~~`

e.g.

```
if( ~~score > ~~tot)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert them to int, before comparing. Like this., Also add a check if those strings are integer or not using `isNaN` .

`if( parseInt(score) > parseInt(tot))`

Comment: To prevent some input "mistakes", one should use the radix as well: `parseInt( stringVal, 10 )`.

Comment: typo `pareseInt` vs `parseInt`?